# Rails/Heroku test a future time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, heroku

I have alot of features that rely on expiration dates and future times, we use timecop in our rspec/unit tests but I was wondering if anyone had any clever solutions for how a product/QA person could emulate some time in the future when they are testing a feature, like if it would be possible to start the heroku server based on an environment variable with some future time etc?

An example would be you have a coupon, with an expires_at timestamp 3 days in the future, if I wanted my QA/product team to be able to quickly see that state, where its expired, is there a clever way to do that by tricking the server somehow? We could build tools to auto-adjust the records to expire at the current time etc. But when you start to have alot of features that have such future time based logic it becomes more unpleasant

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to test a production environment in the future. Even if there was, it wouldn't make sense to do so. All you should be concerned about is if it works right now. 2 high-level questions to ask are...

1. Does it work in your development/test environments (in other words, is the logic correct?)
2. Does your production service provide some type of task management and how reliable is it?

Because you are using Heroku and did not specify the exact problem you are facing, lets just say you are using Heroku Scheduler, as an example.

If your application logic is correct and you are able to run a task with `$ heroku run rails your_task`, then there is nothing left for you to test. You can be confident that it will work. Anything beyond that would be testing Heroku itself (or whatever production service you are using).

Comment: Thanks Mark, apologies if my question wasn't clear, I'll update the question, but I am referring more to if you have something say with an expired_at timestamp, and you want your designer to be able to easily fast forward to the state where it is expired, what would the best way to be able to do that?

Comment: no task is run the state of the object is just different and therefore impacts the application differently

Comment: agreed, but I guess what I am looking for is a way for non-devs to be able to emulate and test

Comment: I'm skeptical about how an object's state changes once the `expiration_date` is met without a task. If there is logic in the code that checks for this...it almost certainly belongs in a task instead. As @max suggested, creating a separate environment for non-devs to test against expired records would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a piece of middleware that uses Timecop to modify the time on your staging environment:

```
# /app/middlewares/time_traveler.rb
class TimeTraveler
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    Timecop.travel(Time.local(2015, 10, 21, 12, 0, 0)) do
      Rails.logger.info('Great Scott!')
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

```
# /config/environments/staging.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
  config.middleware.use TimeTraveler
end
```

This uses a fixed time but you could use input from the request (env.request) such as parameters, headers or cookies instead.

However this only changes Rubys interpretation of time. And not:

- The databases concept of time. For example any code that uses the SQL `NOW()` function may break.
- System time. Any cron jobs or recurring tasks will stil be running on a different clock.
- Time in the client. Caches will be invalid. Things might break.

I would not consider doing this on the actual production server to be a good idea. Instead setup a staging environment (a seperate Heroku app).

Answer (score 0):

I've created my own solution for this: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_time_travel

This gem is using a timecop too, but it has a UI and you can select any datetime.